# Error in Automator Open File

Tags: automator, reminders

I have a Service in Automator that works fine till I try to use the Open File action

[image]

In the New Reminder widow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because of reputation, but I had a lot of trouble with Automator until I allowed all the apps into Preferences/Security/Privacy/Accessibility. Maybe you didn't add Calendar?

Comment: ok, lets fix your reputation :)